# How to center cols in rows (Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to center cols but I couldn't solve it properly. I'm waiting your ideas. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <h3>Google Maps</h3>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img alt="Google Maps" src="http://www.jontheboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Google-maps-logo-180x180.png" style="height: 180px; width: 180px; display: block;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <h3>Bootstrap</h3>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img alt="Bootstrap" src="http://collectit.fr/uploads/ressources/3.png" style="height: 180px; width: 180px; display: block;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <h3>JavaScript</h3>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img alt="JavaScript" src="http://image.slidesharecdn.com/organizando-js-tablelessconf-120828084246-phpapp01/95/evento-front-end-sp-organizando-o-javascript-6-728.jpg?cb=1346143491" style="height: 180px; width: 180px; display: block;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I tested it here, http://www.bootply.com/pM4tcqfqhA. All I did was wrap it in the proper parent div with class "container".

Comment: It's not centered as far as I see :) The right space is larger than the left.